# Employer Published Resume Online

Tags: hiring-process, job-search

My wife and I typically like to search our names on Google to see what information comes up about us. Well yesterday, my wife found that her resume was published to an online site www.pdfonline.com, without her discretion. This site appears to have a service that allows PDF files to be manipulated and converted between different formats. I can only assume that an employer that my wife applied to is using this service. It's a little frightening to see this considering it contains all her contact information and other identifying information.

I would like to know if there are any legal implications to this. Are there laws that companies must follow with regard to safeguarding personal information in resumes? I expect that when prospective candidates apply to positions that their resumes be treated with the utmost confidentiality.

Edit: The jobs being applied to are in the United States.

Comment: I would hope the information in the resume is public knowlege ( i.e. phone number, full name, ect ).  The only thing semi-private is her work history.

Comment: Luckily, there is nothing "too personal".  However, it's unsettling to know that they just published this information online. There is no need to do that. This should be kept internally. I don't know if this is a stretch but we want to contact PDFOnline and ask them to remove the resume and possibly provide us the source.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - it isn't merely reasonable, I'm pretty sure they would do it.  The people that posted it might have put a whole batch of documents out there without realizing that this was one of them.  As part of the OPs request, they should ask that the employer review all their content, and remove anything that could be viewed as private or sensitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think we can cover the legal case here.  I'd say it's worth talking to someone if you want to know the legal stance.

But I'd start with a formal but cordial note to the site:

- Your wife should inform them that this is her original composition and she did not grant rights for public display
- They have exposed personal information without her consent.
- Ask them to take it down and remove this information from their repository and give them a deadline.

If the information is still up after the deadline, then you may want legal counsel for forcing them on this.

If you want to vindictive, you can also ask for the source of the information, but I'm not sure how much you want to push there unless you really are considering a law suit.

Comment: We contacted the site that had the document and asked them to take it down. They did. As for the source, they said they do not have that information. I find that hard to believe. At least the PDF is no longer public.

Comment: Interesing... it could be that a place your wife submitted the resume is using this PDF-making service as part of their internal process.  And the service saw the material, saw that it looked nice, and yanked it without the original company's knowledge.  Sleazy, but possible.  Without a legal battle we'll probably never know.  Glad you got it down!